# Existing Xcode/Swift3 App Suddenly Does Not Recognize Parse Framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, parse-server

I have an app that has been published to the App Store for almost a year now.  The app has been using parse framework (not installed with cocoapods) all this time and works fine.

I recently opened the existing project for this app in Xcode after a few weeks of working on a different project (new project does not use parse and is not related to existing app in any way) and suddenly the project has an error "No such module 'Parse'"

I have read every thread on stackoverflow, GitHub, and other random places related to this topic.  I have tried every suggestion I have found in these resources and nothing is fixing the error.

I have done the following:

1. deleted all derived data, quit Xcode, reopened project & cleaned
2. adjust the search framework paths in the target build settings (tried this about a dozen times)
3. deleted the parse framework and added back, cleaned project

I would be eternally grateful for any assistance in resolving this error.  I've spent over 2 weeks trying to resolve.

[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: Are you using cocoapods? If so, can you post your podfile

Comment: Not using cocoapods

Comment: I'm sure you've tried this, but I had an issue where `import Parse` would show an error until I actually tried to build/run the app. Once I built it, the issue went away.

Comment: Error appears when I try to build

Answer (score 0):

I have FINALLY resolved this issue.

***root cause:***  the framework files that are referenced within the project were originally stored on my desktop.  I recently cleaned my desktop and deleted files I thought I didn't need anymore...wrong!  the parse framework files were there and moved/deleted.

***fix:***  for me, I needed to get the original files back so I was able to reinstall the framework files by getting them from the original location I got them (pulled them in from a parse starter project I downloaded from GitHub).  bottom line is that I needed to reinstate the framework files.

the frameworks should have the suitcase icon as shown below:

[image]

if the suitcase icon is not there then the frameworks are not installed correctly.